# JavaCV v0.9 - getAffineTransform() how to use

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision, javacv, affinetransform

I want to use getAffineTransform(...) method in my Android (Java) app, but unfortunately I have seen that there are only the following options:
getAffineTransform(Mat src, Mat dsc) and getAffineTransform(Point2f src, Point2f dsc)

In OpenCV: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=getaffinetransform#getaffinetransform 
Use: Mat getAffineTransform(const Point2f src[], const Point2f dst[])

Why can't use this method with Point2f arrays? 
Maybe I know the wrong use, but how to use it correctly?

Thank you!
Regards

Csaba